# How can I specify a custom XML/SVG namespace with D3.js?

Tags: svg, d3.js, xml-namespaces

I am trying to define my own namespace inside a SVG so I can use my own tags and attributes. If I understand [correctly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course), the SVG should look like this:

```
<svg xmlns:myns="http://www.example.com/whatever/">
  <g myns:mycustomattr="123">
    ...
```

I am adding root SVG element through D3, but adding a namespace to it with `attr` fails:

```
var svg = d3.select("#container")
  .append("svg")
    .attr('xmlns:myns', 'http://www.example.com/whatever/')
```

The code above results in: *NamespaceError: An attempt was made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces*

What would be the correct way to add namespace to SVG using D3.js?

Comment: Have you seen [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Namespaces)?

Comment: Actually, I did - I see from Robert's answer that I didn't understand it correctly though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just set [d3.ns.prefix](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Namespaces)

```
d3.ns.prefix.myns = "http://www.example.com/whatever/";
```

Then use it:

```
var svg = d3.select("#container")
  .append("svg")
    .attr('myns:someAttribute', 'some value');
```